# Adding a positive number to a char unexpectedly decreases it's value

Tags: c++, c++14

I was trying the Caesar Cipher problem and got stuck at a very beginner like looking bug, but I don't know why my code is behaving that way. I added an integer to a char and expect it to increase in value, but I get a negative number instead. Here is my code. Although I found a way around it, but why does this code behave this way?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    char ch ='w';
    int temp;
    temp = int(ch) + 9;
    ch = temp;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    cout<<(int)ch;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
128
-128
```

Comment: Ohh ya, making it unsinged char solves the problem.
Post ur comment as an answer, i will upvote it and put the tick sign

Comment: Before you add two numbers together, you need to make sure you don't overflow the type in which you are doing the addition!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in `temp = int(ch) + 9;`, the cast isn't needed. When you add a `char` and an `int`, the `char` gets promoted to `int`.

Comment: Also, get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default value. In this case, that means changing `int temp; temp = int(ch) + 9;` to `int temp = int(ch) + 9;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A signed `char` type can typically hold values from -128 to 127.

With a value 128 it overflows.

Comment: Note that, unlike with the other types, it is implementation-defined whether a `char` where you don’t specify the signedness is `signed` or `unsigned`.